# Form Email Validation in backend PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I am using a form to get newsletter sign ups on my website. I am using a contact.php file which works well but there is no validation so I occasionaly and sometimes frequently get blank responses.

I'm not sure why this is, but I believe I need validation.

This is my original code

```
<?php
/*

Author: Andrew Walsh
Date: 30/05/2006
Codewalkers_Username: Andrew


This script is a basic contact form which uses AJAX to pass the information to php, thus making the page appear to work without any refreshing or page loading time.

*/

$to = "hello@interzonestudio.com"; //This is the email address you want to send the email to
$subject_prefix = ""; //Use this if you want to have a prefix before the subject

if(!isset($_GET['action']))




{
die("You must not access this page directly!"); //Just to stop people from visiting contact.php normally
}

/* Now lets trim up the input before sending it */


$subject = "Newsletter Sign Up"; //The senders subject
$message = trim($_GET['email']); //The senders subject
$email = trim($_GET['email']); //The senders email address

mail($to,$subject,$message,"From: ".$email.""); //a very simple send

echo 'contactarea|Thank you. We promise you won’t regret it.'; //now lets update the "contactarea" div on the contact.html page. The contactarea| tell's the javascript which div to update.
?>
```

and this is the code I tried to add to validate but it doesnt work.

```
<?php
/*

Author: Andrew Walsh
Date: 30/05/2006
Codewalkers_Username: Andrew


This script is a basic contact form which uses AJAX to pass the information to php, thus making the page appear to work without any refreshing or page loading time.

*/

$to = "jcash1@gmail.com"; //This is the email address you want to send the email to
$subject_prefix = ""; //Use this if you want to have a prefix before the subject

if(!isset($_GET['action']))




{
die("You must not access this page directly!"); //Just to stop people from visiting contact.php normally
}

/* Now lets trim up the input before sending it */


$subject = "Newsletter Sign Up"; //The senders subject
$message = trim($_GET['email']); //The senders subject
$email = trim($_GET['email']); //The senders email address


/* Validation */
$error=0; // check up variable
$errormsg = '<ul class="errorlist">';

/* get it checking */


if(!check_email($email))
{
  $errormsg.=  "<li class='errormessage'>ERROR: not a valid email.</li>";
  $error++;
}

$errormsg .= '</ul>';


if($error == 0) {


mail($to,$subject,$message,"From: ".$email.""); //a very simple send

echo 'contactarea|Thank you. We promise you won’t regret it.'; //now lets update the "contactarea" div on the contact.html page. The contactarea| tell's the javascript which div to update.

 } else { 
    echo 'error|'. $errormsg;
 }

?>
```

Can anyone offer some insight?

---

I cannot for the life of me get this to work...
I am getting an Error with the plugin and I have loaded it correctly

so I tried adding this :

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true) {
  //your email sending code here
} else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
```

like so:

```
<?php
/*

Author: Andrew Walsh
Date: 30/05/2006
Codewalkers_Username: Andrew


This script is a basic contact form which uses AJAX to pass the information to php, thus making the page appear to work without any refreshing or page loading time.

*/

$to = "hello@interzonestudio.com"; //This is the email address you want to send the email to
$subject_prefix = ""; //Use this if you want to have a prefix before the subject

if(!isset($_GET['action']))




{
die("You must not access this page directly!"); //Just to stop people from visiting contact.php normally
}

/* Now lets trim up the input before sending it */

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true) {



$subject = "Newsletter Sign Up"; //The senders subject
$message = trim($_GET['email']); //The senders subject
$email = trim($_GET['email']); //The senders email address


mail($to,$subject,$message,"From: ".$email.""); //a very simple send



echo 'contactarea|<div id="thanks">Thank you. We promise you won’t regret it.</div>'; //now lets update the "contactarea" div on the contact.html page. The contactarea| tell's the javascript which div to update.

} else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}


?>
```

Which is not working. I think it is beauce I have implemented the code in the wrong place but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter_var()` function in PHP for validating email addresses.

For simply validating email addresses in PHP you can use it like this,

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
  echo "Valid email";
}
```

And your code can be improved like this.

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
  mail($to,$subject,$message,"From: ".$email.""); //a very simple send
  echo 'contactarea|Thank you. We promise you won’t regret it.'; //now lets update the "contactarea" div on the contact.html page. The contactarea| tell's the javascript which div to update.
}
else {
  $errormsg.=  "<li class='errormessage'>ERROR: not a valid email.</li>";
  $error++;
  echo '</ul> error|'. $errormsg;
}
```

If you want to know more about it, visit official PHP documentation page here : http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 0):

Or use jquery validation plugin. I highly recommend it.

Code will look similar to below

```
  $( "#myform" ).validate({
   rules: {
   field: {
  required: true,
  email: true
    }
   }
  });
```

Comment: I am trying:  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $("#contactform").validate({
      rules: {
         email: {
            required: true.
               }
         },
         messages: {
            email: "Required Field"
         }
     });
});       but I am getting a TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$("#contactform").validate')

Answer (score 0):

You can use server side validation by using this code

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true) {
  //your email sending code here
} else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
```